# String interpolation acting strange with special characters

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to do file save/remove in .NET (C#), but I bumped into strange behavior.  I have the following string:

```
string baseName = "קומה 1";
string extension = "xyz";
```

I want this string to be concatenated with another string, let's say `"_00"`.
I tried following:

```
string finalName = baseName + "_00." + extension;
string finalInterpolatedName = $"{baseName}_00.{extension}";
string finalInterpolatedNameWithCulture = $"{baseName.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)}_00.{extension}";
```

I'm expecting to get something like strangeString_00.xyz, but instead I'm getting 00_strangeString.xyz. And I just realized that I cannot even write that in any notepad or SO text box, for some reason, after "קומה 1" numbers kept going to the left side. I would like to understand what is happening and why.

Tnx

Comment: Looks like a mixture of left-to-right and right-to-left scripts

Comment: To me as well. but I cannot believe it's happening in the code while explicitly selecting the wanted order of concatenation.

Comment: There might be a difference between the order of characters in the string and how it is displayed. Have a look at finalName.ToCharArray() in the debugger.